# Using Java Custom StanfordCoreNLP Named-Entity-Recognition Model in python

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp

I was wondering how would i go about using a custom NER model I trained in the java CoreNLP in the python CoreNLP?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Stanza's CoreNLP client: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html

When starting your server, start with the property `"ner.model": "/path/to/custom_model.ser.gz"`

You may also want to set the property `"ner.statisticalOnly": True` if you just want to run your NER model. The `ner` annotator will run a large set of additional processes by default.